# Where should a CLI app (written in Node) cache things?

Tags: node.js

I want to write a CLI, distributed as an npm module that exports a bin.

I am happy for users to install it **either** globally **or** as a dev-dependency on a per-project basis (e.g. to be run via an npm script in their project).

When my CLI runs, it will sometimes need to download things in response to user input, and I want to cache those things so the CLI can work faster next time.

**Where should my CLI cache these things?**

I feel somewhere like `~/.my-module-name/cache` would be a smart place *if* my CLI is installed globally. But if a user installs my CLI as a dev-dep in a specific project, then I'm not so sure that's a good place.

I've noticed there's the [configstore](https://github.com/yeoman/configstore) package, which persists things in `~/.config/...`. But this doesn't feel right, as my need is for caching things (totalling a few MB) rather than just configuration.

Comment: How about checking layer wise? First, check for the cached data in the current directory somewhere. If not found, check for the global cache as you mentioned.

Comment: Is it actually OK/recommended to for a module to write into its own directory (ie. somewhere inside a `node_modules` folder)? I know modules do this on their postinstall build scripts, but is it acceptable to do that at runtime? I feel like it could cause problems.

Comment: Agreed, having data cached inside `node_modules` looks fishy. I'd say it is better to save the cached data in the root directory ( where the `package.json` is located ). That could be for example say `my-awesome-project/.your-module/cache`. And analogous to that, you will have `~/.your-module/cache` for your global cache.